# Cannot add data labels to column chart created by python's xlsxwriter module

Tags: python, charts, xlsxwriter

I create a column chart with python's `xlsxwriter` module and I try to add value data labels on top of each column, but the created excel file is empty:

```
'data_labels': {'value': True, 'position': 'above'}
```

And I get no exceptions either. 
When I comment out this line, however, the code runs without errors, the chart is created as expected. Is there a known bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data lable `position` has to match the available positions supported by the Excel chart type.

For example the `above` position in line charts is called `outside_end` for column/bar charts (in Excel).

Check in Excel which is the position you need for the chart type that you have. If you are using a column charts then it should be `outside_end`.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/jmcnamara/excel-writer-xlsx/issues/110) for this to re-map the names for different chart types.

Comment: Thank you, but why aren't there any exceptions? The output excel is just empty.

Comment: And the things written in your answer isn't written in the documentation. Best regards

Comment: As I said above this is an open (i.e., known) issue. It was only discovered recently and I haven't had a chance to patch it yet. Did the proposed solution work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked. Is it possible that you add the feature where user can have different series chart types in same chart? For example one series is column, and other is line series?

Comment: Glad to hear. If it worked then you should accept the answer. *Q. Is it possible that you add the feature where user can have different series chart types in same chart*. That is an open [feature request](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/72). Hopefully it will get added in the future.